What are the ways to publicly store wolfram demonstrations without Wolfram Demonstration project?
The Wolfram Demonstrations project is a nice place to store dynamic, self-contained presentations (based on the Manipulate construct).
The advantages are numerous, including free cloud, description, review, dynamics, and easy code download and reading (as is).
But as disadvantages one can admit the dependency on the latest software and the slow publication process and, thus upgrade of materials (one could admit that the growth of the number of demonstrations is very slow during the last decade).
I wonder what are the effective ways to make demonstrations publicly available without relying on Wolfram's infrastructure. I understand that this will lead to sacrificing some (or most) functionality. The least requirements: code readability and a way to show some dynamics.
A dedicated blog or website is redundant.

can't you just post them at your web page? ofcourse, you have to put the CDF file to download and instructions that user needs the player to run them (if they do not have Mathematica).  That is what I do with my Mathematica demos.

@Nasser, I've taken a look at you site. That is a good approach, indeed. So, you solve the problem of code sourcing it in html. Did you automate the process of code saving in html?

only automation I have is build the Mathematica demos web page using Makefile from Latex. The whole page is written in Latex and tex4ht converts it to HTML.  Everything else was manual. Include making a small movie for each demo and saving the source code as HTML and ofcourse making the CDF and exporting the demo as PDF also.

speaking of Wolfram demo site, a lot of things changed in it from the old days. Now there is no NEXT page button. One only gets first page https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/new  by clicking LATEST on main page https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/  but there is no next page any more. There is no date or author name also below the demo. One has to click on each demo to find this info. It will be also nice to have demos arranged by date. I also noticed that the "live version..." can be slow. May WRI needs bigger server to run these demos on.

@Nasser. About 6 years ago there were 12+ thousand entries. Now only 13+. Also, the presentation template that allows automatic upload only supports the latest MMA. I've tried on previous major versions and all failed. The only way if you have no newer soft is to send a presentation by email. I was going to upload more, but now I have serious doubts.

You may find the following recent video useful: Wolfram Language Repositories, Including the New WL Example Repo and the Demonstrations Project.
